# how to add 1 to the metal value in this code

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi guys I have this code that take a steam listing and match the price (the price is divided into keys and metal ) and i need to modified it so the metal value is equal to the original+1

this is the code
ps: i did not write the code and the man how did is not responding

```
// Match Buttons

function addMatchButtons(){

    const keyEx = /(\d*(?= keys?))/;
    const refEx = /\d*(.\d*)?(?= ref)/;

    // Parse text into a price object
    const parseListingPrice = function(price){
        return {
            keys:  parseFloat(keyEx.exec(price) ? keyEx.exec(price).shift() : 0),
            metal: parseFloat(refEx.exec(price) ? refEx.exec(price).shift() : 0)
        };
    }

    // Do not match these 
    const hasBlacklistedProperties = function(info){
        if( info.data('paint_name')     !== undefined  
            info.data('spell_1')        !== undefined  
            info.data('part_price_1')   !== undefined  
            info.data('killstreaker')   !== undefined 
            info.data('sheen')          !== undefined ){
            return true;
        }
           
        return false;
    }

    // Spawns the actual button
    const spawnMatchButton = function (){
        let element = $(this);   
        const info = element.find('.item');
        const price = parseListingPrice(info.data('listing_price')  "");
        const match = `<a data-postfix="/item/${encodeURIComponent((info.prop('title')  info.data('original-title')).trim())}?keys=${price.keys}&metal=${price.metal}&intent=${info.data('listing_intent')}" title="Match this user's price" target="_blank" class="btn btn-bottom btn-xs btn-success gladiator-context">
                <i class="fa fa-sw fa-tags"></i>
            </a>`;
        
        if(!hasBlacklistedProperties(info) || info.data('listing_intent') === "sell" )
            element.find(".listing-buttons").prepend(match);
    };


    let sellers =   $($(".media-list")[0]);
    let buyers =    $($(".media-list")[1]);

    sellers .find(".listing").each(spawnMatchButton);
    buyers  .find(".listing").each(spawnMatchButton);
```

i tried simply adding +1 after the metal: and it did not work
LOL

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `parseListingPrice`, added + 1 to the metal value. This will increment the metal value by 1 every time the parseListingPrice function is called.

```
const parseListingPrice = function(price){
    return {
        keys:  parseFloat(keyEx.exec(price) ? keyEx.exec(price).shift() : 0),
        metal: parseFloat(refEx.exec(price) ? refEx.exec(price).shift() : 0) + 1 
    };
}
```